# Displaying default value through select tag

Tags: php, html, html-select

I am having trouble passing & displaying default value for select tag. So, I have tried different variants of select and option tag but I am not able to get this right.

I want to fetch different options in form of a drop down menu. I want to display a default value in it. ($categorytemp[$i] in code). On displaying the form

1. A user can update this choice; or
2. A user can select the same choice again; or
3. A user can not change it at all.

Expected result for the above activity should be update, update, default value for $category

Below is the snapshot of my code

```
<select name="category" value="<?php echo $categorytemp[$i] ?>">



                                <?php 

                                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM education_details";
                                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                                            {
                                                $education_category = $row["id"];
                                                $education_name= $row["name"]; 
                                                ?>
                                                <option value='<?php echo $education_category?>'><?php echo $education_name;?></option>
                                                <?php
                                            }
                                ?>
                                </select>
```

I tried using the option tag with selected attribute but that is making things more complicated. For example, if I use

```
<select name="category" value="<?php echo $categorytemp[$i] ?>">
                            <option selected="selected"><?php echo $categorytemp[$i]; ?> </option>


                                <?php 

                                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM education_details";
                                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                                            {
                                                $education_category = $row["id"];
                                                $education_name= $row["name"]; 
                                                ?>
                                                <option value='<?php echo $education_category?>'><?php echo $education_name;?></option>
                                                <?php
                                            }
                                ?>
                                </select>
```

It displays the form as desired but on making no selection, it passes null value in the category. I have gone through questions of similar type asked earlier, but they do not answer my query to my satisfaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick. When no value is selected, pass the default value as value in option

```
<select name="category" >
                        <option value='<?php echo $categorytemp[$i]?>'><?php echo $categorytemp[$i]; ?> </option>


                            <?php 

                                $sql = "SELECT * FROM education_details";
                                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                                        {
                                            $education_category = $row["id"];
                                            $education_name= $row["name"]; 
                                            ?>
                                            <option value='<?php echo $education_category?>'><?php echo $education_name;?></option>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                            ?>
                            </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do it with a "selected" attribute of a given `<option>` and not in the `<select>` tag with the value attribute.

Check these two:

- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

Have you consider using Javascript on the form submit to achieve it?

Another option would be a hidden field with default value before the select and an hidden option of the select field:

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="dropdown" value="default" />
<select name="dropdown">
<option selected disabled hidden style="display: none" value="default"></option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I do this, on user activity = no modifications in the dropdown menu, it passes a null value for $category. I have explained the same in my question as well.

Comment: I dont know javascript. I am just beginning to learn PHP. If there is something you can suggest, I would love to try it.

Comment: @ZigsawConsultancy you could also try setting an option to selected and hiding it with CSS.

Comment: How should i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Is `$categoryTemp[$i]` an ID or a name?  If it is the ID and you are wanting to check the result against it to determine the default option to display then something along these lines would select the option that is equal to the value of $categoryTemp[$i].

`<option <?php echo ($categorytemp[$i] == $education_category ? 'selected' : ''); ?>`

So if `$categorytemp[$i] = 1` and `$education_category = 1` then that option would be marked selected and be displayed when the page loaded